# How to keep expand always the first div of collapsible div onchange of a dropdown in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some collapsed/expanded div which keep first div always open on load.Here I need to keep open first div, also on change the given dropdown,Its working but if I expand anyone and change the dropdown, the expanded div also remains expanded.I tried with $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true; but its not working.Can anyone please help me here is the below code.

### HTML

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="scroll-div">
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}" ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:predicate:reverse track by $index">
        <div class="parents" ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}
        </div>

        <ul class="childs" ng-show="($index == 0 && pristine) || group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list ">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="test()">Sort</button>
    <select ng-model="x" ng-change="changeit()">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</body>
```

### script.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $scope.pristine = true;
  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);
    $scope.pristine = false;
  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'6',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 6',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.test = function() {
$scope.groups.forEach(a => {a.isOpen = false;});
    $scope.pristine = true;

    $scope.predicate = 'id';
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;       
  }
 $scope.changeit = function() {

     $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;

 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working pen with the behaviour I think you want: https://codepen.io/Lahikainen/pen/rPBVeO

Here's the code with a few changes:

**EDIT**: added toggle behaviour for groups

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="scroll-div">
      <div
        style="border:1px solid;"
        id="anchor{{group.id}}"
        ng-repeat="group in groups track by group.id">

        <div class="parents" ng-click="toggleExpand(group)">
          <i ng-class="{
            'glyphicon-minus': isExpandedGroup(group),
            'glyphicon-plus': !isExpandedGroup(group)}">
          </i>
          {{ group.title }}
        </div>

        <ul class="childs" ng-show="isExpandedGroup(group)">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list ">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="sort()">Sort</button>
    <select ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-options="group.title for group in groups">
      <option>{{ group.title }}</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</body>
```

**controller**

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'6',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 6',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];

  $scope.selectedGroup = $scope.groups[0];
  $scope.sortOrderMultiplier = 1;

  $scope.isExpandedGroup = function (group) {
    return group === $scope.selectedGroup;
  }

  $scope.toggleExpand = function (group) {
    if ($scope.selectedGroup === group) {
      $scope.selectedGroup = undefined;
    } else {
      $scope.selectedGroup = group; 
    }
  }

  $scope.sort = function () {
    $scope.sortOrderMultiplier *= -1;

    $scope.groups.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.id > b.id) {
        return 1 * $scope.sortOrderMultiplier;
      }
      if (a.id < b.id) {
        return -1 * $scope.sortOrderMultiplier;
      }
      return 0;
    })
  }
});
```

Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

**EDIT** Add justifications on why I refactored your code:

One of your requirements seems to be that only one group can be expanded at one time. For this reason I added a `selectedGroup` to the model rather than adding an `isOpen` property to each group.

This code is needlessly complicated when all you need is a `selectedGroup` model:
`ng-show="($index == 0 && pristine) || group.isOpen"`

Your `open` function receives a group as its parameter. You then filter the `groups` array to find the reference to the group you already have a reference to. You then set the `isOpen` property. All you need to do for that function is `item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;` This is the same with your `closeOthers` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Here it should not be like this.No need to see sorting it was already working fine.My issue was whenever you change dropdown always first div which contains title 1 should expand.That is also working in my code,but when I expand any div for ex second div and again if I change dropdown first and that expanded div remains expand

Comment: I made those changes because it seems that one of your requirements is that only one group can be expanded. I think it's better to have a `selectedGroup` model instead of having a boolean on each item - this made your code much more complicated than it needed to be. In any case I've updated the pen so that it always selects the group with id === 1.